# PostInsertEventListener executed before the DB was updated

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I put a Thread.sleep(50000) within the listener, to prove this, and the data literally wasn't stored in the DB for 50s.

This is strange and rather disappointing, because I am passing the id of the entity (which is there BTW) to a web service, accessing the same database. If I don't make the call in a new thread, the web service throws an exception because the data isn't there.

I could apply a hacky method, and make the call within a new thread, with possibly some time delay before, but that would be ugly

Please, help.

Comment: PostInsert != commit. Make sure you properly use transactions. In your case it seems that you were just trying to query DB after the insert, but commit hasn't happened at that point.

Answer (score 1):

It's not related to the fact that the insert is done after the listener. It's related to the fact that the commit of the transaction is done after. Your web service uses another transaction as the one where you insert the data, so it doesn't see the inserted data until the inserting transaction has committed.

You'll need two-phase commit to do what you want. Invoke your web service through a JMS queue and make sure the JMS engine and the database are both handled by a unique, XA, transaction manager.